# Why is there spacing between my elements? ... and other CSS questions

Tags: html, css

I've created a fiddle that's almost what I'm looking for, but still unsure of a couple things:

http://jsfiddle.net/LrAd3/

Here are the things I'm not understanding:

- I've specified both the image and the listbox to be 512px in height but they are very slightly different heights. (EDIT: I believe this is because images and listboxes have different box sizing techniques.  Adjusting this seems to fix the problem.)
- Why is there a small gap between the image and the listbox? (EDIT: Because both the img and span are inline elements so spaces and newlines are significant.)
- I know vertical-align is important here but I can't find a good source to understand how it works. I know it is different for images vs tables vs other block elements, but does anyone have a reference with an explanation?  For example, I tried wrapping the img and listbox with a div and setting 'vertical-align' to top there, but it didn't do anything until I set:

`vertical-align: top;`

directly on the image. (EDIT: I've found more info on this and I believe I'm using it correctly.)

Thanks for taking a look. And any suggestions of improvements would be appreciated.

EDIT: I believe all my questions are answered now.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Gap is due to the borders

Comment: They each have 1px border. I removed the boxes on top to simplify things, double checked margins/padding, still appearing.

Comment: No, you're right. With borders removed, the size is the same. Odd.

Comment: Borders are added to the width/height, also img is inline. if you but <img><select> directly together with no newline the gap is gone. You could make it also a block element and float it or whatever.

Comment: @2called-chaos: Good suggestion about removing the gap, but why are the heights different?  They all have a 1px border so the border can't be the explanation, right?

Comment: Might I suggest you edit the title to mention `select`. I can see this being an issue for others, and it annoying part is with the default values of the `select`. Something like Select and Div have differing heights with borders, might help others find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the small space between, it's because they are set to `inline-block`, as someone mentioned in the comments. If you remove the physical space in the HTML code, you'll be good. Alternatively, you can make them both `display:block` and `float:left`, but you'll need to use a clearfix after them.

The different height part is harder to find, but I tracked it down. The problem child here is the `box-sizing` attribute. `div` has a default value for this of `content-box`. `select`'s default value is `border-box`. You'll need three values though, to cover all browsers.

This fixes it:

```
select {
    -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LrAd3/39/)

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: this does not remove the space between the image and the list

Comment: It did in Firefox. Updated to fix in Chrome and other browsers.

Comment: you fixed only the first point. how is the second one supposed to be fixed?

Comment: @AndyM: Thanks!  I actually played with box-sizing but couldn't get it to make a difference. Thanks for figuring it out!

Comment: @Anubhav: Somebody else solved this on a comment above.  This is because they are inline elements so spaces and newlines are significant.

Comment: how do you remove the space between the image and the list ?

Comment: Edited to explain how to fix the first part, Anubhav.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (although AndyM's answer above is perfectly fine) to the white-space issue with the `vertical align` would be to set the containing div's `font-size` to 0px. This will eliminate white space between the inline elements. You will, of course, need to set a different (positive) font-size for the child elements.

Comment: Yep, that would do it for the horizontal spacing.